# Запрет на посещение админки определённой роли в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем доброго времени суток.
**Задача**:
Есть 2 роли:Низкий/Высокий
Есть админ страница с 1 выпадающим списком:Низкая/Высокая
Если стоит Низкая,то человек с ролью "Высокий" не может зайти в админку,человек с ролью "Низкий" может войти
Если поставили Высокая,то человек с ролью "Высокий" может зайти в админку, человек с ролью "Низкий" тоже может войти.
**Как сделал я**:
Поставил разрешению у низкого просмотр.

```
 return [
    'hight' => [
        'type' => 1,

    ],
    'low' => [
        'type' => 1,
        'children' => [
            'view',
        ],
    ],
    'view' => [
        'type' => 2,
        'description' => 'view',
    ],
];
```

И проверяю на разрешение условием

```
Yii::$app->user->can('view')
```

А дальше ступор...
Куда нужно записывать переменную из выпадающего списка "низкая/высокая",чтобы давать,отбирать право просмотра у роли "Высокий".И вообще какая логика будет,что нужно изменять. не совсем понятно.
Кривое объяснение,извините.
Надеюсь на Вашу помощь,заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Похоже вам стоит глянуть в сторону правил, в yii1 они назывались бизнес-правилами, во вторых просто правила) yii\rbac\Rule - описываете свое правило, которое будет проверять что у вас там в настройках админ панели и кто у нас пользователь, и возвращать true/false для метода. В деталях не помню с ходу не опишу в ответе.

Comment: @Bookin как я понял,вы имеете в виду проверку Permission
Но смысл в том,что у одной роли их 2,и нужно через выпадающий список выбирать к какому правилу обращаться,а этого я не знаю как :С

Comment: Правило оно у вас одно - зайти в админку, что то типа `createPermission('openAdminPanel')`, вот если ему задать правило - `->ruleName = $rule->name;` и в правиле проверить какой тип у пользователя и какая настройка в админке - `return $user->type == $setting->dropdown->value`, то оно должно отработать так вам нужно, в теории))

Comment: Сам не могу держать все это в голове, советую кучу раз прочитать статью - https://habrahabr.ru/post/177873/, часть про RBAC, что бы понять в целом концепцию, далее накладывать на свои реальности, могу сказать что у вас уже где то, полюбому, косяк с построением правил

Comment: @Bookin Благодарю за ответы и статью,сейчас буду шерстить)

Answer (score 1):

Ви можете использовать поведение для запрета или разрешения доступа к контроллеру или определённым действиям пользователям.

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
            //тут правила для доступа, каждое в своём массиве
                [
                    //разрешить доступ
                    'allow' => true,
                    //к методам(указывать название какое будет у метода в адресной стороке)
                    //если упустить свойство actions правило будет применяться ко всем методам
                    'actions' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'delete'],
                    //тут через запятую ['роль1','роль2', 'роль3'] можно указывать для кого активно правило
                    'roles' => ['role'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

И таким образом вы избежите лишних условных конструкций и постоянных вызовов `Yii::$app->user->can('view')`